# How to send dataSet response from web api and receive it on MVC Controller in dataset object

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to send Dataset response from `Web API` and want to receive it on my `Controller` method as a dataSet by converting `Json` response from Api to into it.

**- API Method:**

```
public DataSet GetAllProducts()
        {
            //return products;

            var ds = new DataSet();
            var conn = DACUtil.GetConnection();
            try
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from Employee, Company where Employee.Emp_id='2' and Company.Emp_id=2", conn);
                var da = new SqlDataAdapter { SelectCommand = cmd };
                ds.Tables[0].TableName = "Employee";
                ds.Tables[1].TableName = "Company";      
                da.Fill(ds);
                ds.AcceptChanges();

            }
            finally
            {
                conn?.Dispose();
            }
            return ds;
        }
```

**- Controller Receiving Method:**

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:57589");
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));  
                var response = client.GetAsync("api/products").Result; 
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    using (HttpContent content = response.Content)
                    { 
                        string jsonS=await content.ReadAsStringAsync(); 
                        var ds = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataSet>(jsonS); 
                    }
}
```

JsonS receive response in Json, but `var ds = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataSet>(jsonS)`; throw an exception in the conversion.

Comment: what is the exception?

Comment: try JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jsonS);

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Thanks for your kind assistance, I'm exited to tell you that, now the above code is working fine, the exception was something else. :) , I'm appreciate your efforts for me.